# Передача по ссылке в Java

Tags: java

Вопрос просто на понимание, как оно в Java работает. Могу ли я в конструкторе Container удалить объект Chunk?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chunk ch = new Chunk();
        Container cont = new Container(ch);
        System.out.println(ch.data); // тут как бы должна быть ошибка
    }
}

class Container {
    Container(Chunk ch) {
        ch = null; // могу ли я удалить объект Chunk?
    }
}

class Chunk {
    public String data = "data";
}
```

Comment: Нет. Объекты не удаляются явно, только когда на них пропадают все ссылки. В данном случае null присваивать бессмыссленно - все равно на следующей команде ссылка `ch` пропадет по выходе из коструктора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Чтобы объект полностью удалился, необходимо убрать все ссылки на него.